# NameError: name 'queue' is not defined

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot and in one part I have:

```
queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
```

and when I run the code all it says is "NameError: name 'queue' is not defined"

my entire code is:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = 'This is my bots token ofc'

queue.Queue(maxsize=0)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command(aliases=['8ball', 'eight ball', 'eightball', 'magicball', 'magic ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['As I see it, yes.',
                 'Ask again later.',
                 'Better not tell you now.',
                 'Cannot predict now.',
                 'Concentrate and ask again.',
                 'Don’t count on it.',
                 'It is certain.',
                 'It is decidedly so.',
                 'Most likely.',
                 'My reply is no.',
                 'My sources say no.',
                 'Outlook not so good.',
                 'Outlook good.',
                 'Reply hazy, try again.',
                 'Signs point to yes.',
                 'Very doubtful.',
                 'Without a doubt.',
                 'Yes.',
                 'Yes – definitely.',
                 'You may rely on it.']
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responses)}')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author

    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.orange()
    )

    embed.set_author(name='Help')
    embed.add_field(name='!ping', value='Returns Pong!', inline=False)

    await client.send_message(author, embed=embed)

@client.command()
async def Need(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'it works')
    Queue.put(client.user.message)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: ...*why* do you have a line that's just `queue.Queue(maxsize=0)`?

Comment: You're not importing `queue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not import the queue. Use

> import  queue

```
>>> import  queue
>>> queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
<queue.Queue object at 0x7fb8d8e1e4a8>
>>>
```

Here's my terminal output, showing queue object.

Comment: That'll suppress the error message, but it won't change the fact that this code makes no sense.

Comment: The question does not ask if the code makes sense or not. it asks for solution and I gave it. may be he is a beginner who is trying to learn something new and will figure it out eventually. We all have been there, right ?

Comment: Yeah they're absolutely right I'm just trying to learn something new so thank you for the answer even tho I found it out by reading the documentation of discord.py. I wish I could make your answer votes go up.

Comment: @ILikeRiceKrispies Good for you but remember from next time try looking into documentations first and if it doesn't solve your problem then only ask it here.